# Correct way to connect AWS Secret Manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to connect to AWS Secret manage, on local it works fine on the python server it gives "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"
error

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
            service_name='secretsmanager',
            region_name=region_name
        )
```

So I had 2 ways to correct this :

First Method:

```
 session = boto3.session.Session()
        client = session.client(
                service_name='secretsmanager',
                region_name=region_name,aws_access_key_id=Xxxxxx,
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxx

            )
```

Second Method: To have this in a config file (Which will again expose keys)

```
 session = boto3.session.Session()
        client = session.client(
                service_name='secretsmanager',
                region_name=region_name,aws_access_key_id=confg.access,
aws_secret_access_key=confg.key

            )
```

Arent, we exposing our key and access keys in github  if we are specifying it here.?

What is the correct way to access Secret Manager without specifying it here

Comment: What do you mean by "the python server"? Are you referring to an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, you should **assign an IAM Role to the instance** and grant the necessary permissions to that IAM Role to allow it to use AWS Secrets Manager. If it is _not_ an Amazon EC2 instance, then use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store IAM User credentials in a configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct you shouldn't pass your access key and secret key to any running server or service in AWS to avoid exposing it. On your local machine, it worked because your environment is getting your user's permissions via AWS CLI.

What you need to do for a server is to add to the service role a policy allowing it to access the Secrets Manager, then you won't face permissions issues anymore

On [Permissions policy examples - AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html) can find examples of how those policies need to be.

And on [Assign an IAM Role to an EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/) you can see how to attach a role with a specific policy to an EC2 instance.

Comment: How would the server those which role i am using? Can you please give a example

Comment: @Xi12 on the Answer Post I attached an example of how to pass a role to a EC2 Instance if that's where you are running your "python server" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#attach-iam-role. If it's not an EC2 Instance but other AWS Service it would be pretty similar. If you are running the "python server" outside AWS you will need to configure the AWS CLI in the server